# How to use xargs to submit multiple jobs on slurm

Tags: xargs, slurm

Hi I have about 100+ files i need to submit very similar jobs for on slurm. I am trying to use xargs to loop through these files and submit but it is not working as expected. Any advice?

```
file.txt=
file1a file1b file1
.
.
.
file100a file100b file100

cat SpleenGlia/data/file.txt | xargs -l bash -c ‘sbatch --job-name=$3 --output=SpleenGlia/Aligned/$3 SpleenGlia/script.sh $1 $2 $3’
```

I want to submit to slurm using sbatch. The script.sh is a script that uses all 3 variables. i want to submit with the job name being the file name (third variable) and output to a file with the file name.

Running the above code gives me

```
--job-name=: ‘sbatch: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start indexing at 0, not 1. See the examples below, I added the underscores to highlight the missing value `$3`:

```
$ cat file.txt  | xargs -l bash -c 'echo arguments _$1_ _$2_ _$3_'
arguments _file1b_ _file1_ __
arguments _file100b_ _file100_ __
```

The correct one, stating at `$0`:

```
$ cat file.txt  | xargs -l bash -c 'echo arguments _$0_ _$1_ _$2_'
arguments _file1a_ _file1b_ _file1_
arguments _file100a_ _file100b_ _file100_
```

This can be the reason for the error, since the `--job-name=` receives no argument.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the wrong kind of quotes. The error says:

```
--job-name=: ‘sbatch: command not found
```

so it appears Bash takes the quote as part of the executable to run. (And indeed it appears to be ‘ rather than ' or ".) Try replacing the quotes with double quotes (`"`)

Answer (score 0):

How about using `awk` to format the command as text and piping it to the subprocess via `xargs`:

```sh
cat awk.txt | awk '{printf("sbatch --job-name=%s --output=SpleenGlia/Aligned/%s SpleenGlia/script.sh %s", $3, $3, $0)}' | xargs -I{} sh -c "{}"
```